# IIS 10 not setting Asp.Net cookie for session state

Tags: asp.net, iis, session-cookies

I have migrated a website from IIS 7 on MS Server 2008 to IIS 10 on MS Server 2019 and I am unable to set the session state cookie.

I've configured the Session State feature in IIS at the app pool level and at the site level to use InProc for session state, with a named cookie. I've also tried to add this configuration into the web.config file directly.

This is the section of the web.config I have set:

```html
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" name=".MYSITEAUTH" protection="All" slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>
```

A cookie is being set on the client, but not with the .MYSITEAUTH property of the user.

This is the config of IIS for the site's Session State:
[image: IIS Session State settings]

My hypothesis is that this is a configuration issue due to the same code and database not working on two different machines with the same web.config..?

Does anyone have any good steps to follow to enable asp.net session cookies on the client or any gotchas for setting this up in IIS 10 with Server 2019? No idea why this could be any different to the existing configuration but it is certainly something to do with IIS pushing out cookies.

Thanks!

Comment: What you see in IIS Manager reflects the final configuration used by IIS/ASP.NET. So which web.config did you modify? Also did you set a site/application/virtual directory? Important information is missing above.

Comment: @HCdev are you have solution ?